# (Linq To) XML add all the elements in path that don't exist

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have a XML schema that looks like this:

```
<InnerNodeType1 Name="...">
 <InnerNodeType2 Name="...">
  <Leaf ID="..." />
 </InnerNodeType2>
</InnerNodeType1>
```

`InnerNodeType1` and `InnerNodeType2` can be nested like:

```
<InnerNodeType1 Name="...">
 <InnerNodeType1 Name="...">
  <InnerNodeType1 Name="...">
   <InnerNodeType2 Name="...">
    <Leaf ID="..." />
   </InnerNodeType2 Name="...">
  </InnerNodeType1>
 </InnerNodeType1>
</InnerNodeType1>
```

What holds always:

- There is at least one `InnerNodeType1` in the path
- There is at least one `InnerNodeType2` in the path
- `InnerNodeType2` has one and only one `LeafNode`
- There are just 2 types of innernodes

Basically is a path like: `InnerNodeType1\...\InnerNodeType1\InnerNodeType2\...\InnerNodeType2\Leaf`.

Given 3 strings containing: path for InnerNodeType1, path for InnerNodeType2 and the leaf, I want to add in the XML file, the elements that are missing. If some part of the path is already there, then just add new elements as child nodes.

How can I do this using C# and (Linq to) XML?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you simply want to add element nodes given in the path(s)? If I understand you correctly then you could do that as follows:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XDocument doc = new XDocument();
        Add(doc, @"root\cont1", "cont2", "leaf");
        Add(doc.Root, @"cont1\cont1", "cont2", "leaf");
        Add(doc.Root, "cont1", "cont2", "leaf");
        Add(doc.Root, @"cont1\cont1\cont1\cont1", @"cont2\cont2", "leaf");

        doc.Save(Console.Out);
    }
    static void Add(XContainer cont, string path1, string path2, string path3)
    {
        Add(cont, path1 + "\\" + path2 + "\\" + path3);
    }

    static void Add(XContainer cont, string path)
    {
        Add(cont, path.Split('\\'));
    }

    private static void Add(XContainer cont, IEnumerable<string> names)
    {
        XName name = names.FirstOrDefault();
        if (name == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        XContainer child = cont.Element(name);
        if (child == null)
        {
            child = new XElement(name);
            cont.Add(child);
        }
        Add(child, names.Skip(1));
    }
}
```

That outputs the following XML:

```
<root>
  <cont1>
    <cont2>
      <leaf />
    </cont2>
    <cont1>
      <cont2>
        <leaf />
      </cont2>
      <cont1>
        <cont1>
          <cont2>
            <cont2>
              <leaf />
            </cont2>
          </cont2>
        </cont1>
      </cont1>
    </cont1>
  </cont1>
</root>
```

That does in no way check whether the conditions on the names and the number of certain elements is ensured, it simply adds what is not there.